# EXCEL VBA: Listview object feature not found when exporting XLAM file to another machine

Tags: excel, vba, listview, compiler-errors

Writing a quick function to help my colleagues. Using the ListView object from the tools-> Additional Controls -> Microsoft Listview.

When I export the file as an encrypted add-in i.e. .Xlam file. I get the following error

```
Compile error:
Object Library feature not supported
     Ok    HELP
```

As usual MS help is useless. I opened up the code and find that the **Listview** object is lost in the process. Same Office spec (2010), pretty much same PC install Image.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First, please navigate to Tools / References and look for a library with "[Missing]" next to it.  There is probably a different DLL version (for Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library) of this control between the two machines.

Second, try relinking OLE automation, as mentioned [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/693594-compile-error-object-library-feature-not-supportted.html):
[image]

1. Navigate to Tools / References.
2. Uncheck "OLE Automation".
3. Click OK.
4. Navigate to References again and check "OLE Automation".
5. Click OK.

Comment: Checked the References and the specific control for listview version 6.0, 
nothing missing :(

Comment: I found someone mentioning a similar problem on a different site.  They removed and then relinked the reference for OLE Automation.

Comment: I'm quite new to VBa... lets call it a casual user. Any Idea how to relink the reference using VBA code?

Comment: Ok so tried... lstview As **MSComctlLib.** ListView infront of the ListView definition... No luck